# Any way to bring Unity3d to the foreground?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have sent my user out to the browser with `Application.OpenURL`. And now I want to programatically bring unity back to the foreground.

Is there any way to do it without a plugin?

Thanks.

Comment: I use https://stackoverflow.com/a/18052274/254109

Comment: what platform do you use? Actually, there is fancy way to do it but need to use webview platform dependent.

Comment: Where are you sending the user to? Is this your own webpage where you have control over the code executed on said page? Or is it a general page?

Comment: @BrianChoi I don't know about peterept but I am using Windows 10.

Answer (score 3):

Use `GetActiveWindow` to get the window's handle before you send the user away, then use `SetForegroundWindow` using that handle.  Before you use `SetForegroundWindow`, you can [try simulating an Alt keypress](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13881647/1092820) to bring up a menu to abide by [certain limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20445272/1092820) of `SetForegroundWindow`:

```
private IntPtr unityWindow;

[DllImport("user32.dll")] 
static extern IntPtr GetActiveWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll")] 
static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd); 

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);

const int ALT = 0xA4;
const int EXTENDEDKEY = 0x1;
const int KEYUP = 0x2;

private void SendUser() 
{
    unityWindow = GetActiveWindow();

    Application.OpenURL("http://example.com");

    StartCoroutine(RefocusWindow(30f));
}


private IEnumerator RefocusWindow(float waitSeconds) {
    // wait for new window to appear
    yield return new WaitWhile(() => unityWindow == GetActiveWindow());

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitSeconds);

    // Simulate alt press
    keybd_event((byte)ALT, 0x45, EXTENDEDKEY | 0, 0);

    // Simulate alt release
    keybd_event((byte)ALT, 0x45, EXTENDEDKEY | KEYUP, 0);

    SetForegroundWindow(unityWindow);
}
```

Comment: I fixed the IntPtr compiler error but it still doesn't seem to work in Windows 10. It flashes down in the task bar but the window doesn't actually get focus.

Comment: @glenneroo There are some [limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20445272/1092820) with when `SetForegroundWindow` will bring a window to the foreground vs. just flash its bar in the task bar. It seems you can try sending an alt press to bring up a menu, which allows another window (unity in this case) to take control of the foreground. I edited my answer to provide some more info.

Comment: This solution works great on Windows 10 from a Windows_x64 desktop build.

Comment: @ClayFowler thank you for the feedback :)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Unity3D in Windows, try below code after calling Application.OpenURL(...) :

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

var prc = Process.GetProcessesByName("..."); //Get Unity's process, or 
var prc = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
if (prc.Length > 0) 
    SetForegroundWindow(prc[0].MainWindowHandle);
```

Comment: No luck yet. The code above always returns 0 for window handle. I changed it to EnumWindows and I do get a valid window handle. But calling SetForegroundWIndow() is having no effect. I'll keep digging.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on Unity 5.0.1 / Windows 8.1:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class ForeGrounder : MonoBehaviour {

    private const uint LOCK = 1;
    private const uint UNLOCK = 2;

    private IntPtr window;

    void Start() {
        LockSetForegroundWindow(LOCK);
        window = GetActiveWindow();
        StartCoroutine(Checker());
    }

    IEnumerator Checker() {
        while (true) {

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
            IntPtr newWindow = GetActiveWindow();

            if (window != newWindow) {
                Debug.Log("Set to foreground");
                SwitchToThisWindow(window, true);
            }
        }
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetActiveWindow();
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool LockSetForegroundWindow(uint uLockCode);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern void SwitchToThisWindow(IntPtr hWnd, bool fAltTab);
}
```

Comment: [SwitchToThisWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-switchtothiswindow) - *This function is not intended for general use. It may be altered or unavailable in subsequent versions of Windows.*

Comment: The problem is in `window = GetActiveWindow();` when the user switches to another app before this code is run, i.e. before the app initializes. Then the result is `0`.

Answer (score 0):

For Mac Standalone we can try

```
public void OpenURLInDefaultBrowser(string URL)
    {
```

#if UNITY_STANDALONE_OSX

Screen.fullScreenMode = FullScreenMode.Windowed;

#endif
Application.OpenURL(URL);

```
        StartCoroutine(ReFocusUnity());
    }

    private IEnumerator ReFocusUnity()
    {
        //You can wait for some seconds or wait for any callback you are expecting
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5f);
```

#if UNITY_STANDALONE_OSX

```
        Screen.fullScreenMode = FullScreenMode.FullScreenWindow;
```

#endif
}