Bring Word (or other window) opened from application to foreground
After I open a Word document(or any other file with some program) from the application, I would like it to show up at the forefront of everything else. But I have a problem with it opening in the foreground and the window stays in the background at times. I have done some research on this subject but so far without success.

Process fileopener = new Process();
fileopener.StartInfo.FileName = "explorer";
fileopener.StartInfo.Arguments = $"\"{filePath}\"";
fileopener.Start();

IntPtr intPtr = fileopener.MainWindowHandle;

And now I've circulated two possible approaches that everyone is taking.

The simple one
(not working)

ShowWindowAsync(intPtr ,3);
SetForegroundWindow(intPtr);


Much more complicated(also does not work)

Many articles say why this easy approach doesn't work and that you need to bypass the Win32 API a bit.
One of the posts on this topic(https://stackoverflow.com/a/19136480/13698760)



The system restricts which processes can set the foreground window. A process can set the foreground window only if one of the following conditions is true:

The process is the foreground process.
The process was started by the foreground process.
The process received the last input event.
There is no foreground process.
The foreground process is being debugged.
The foreground is not locked (see LockSetForegroundWindow).
The foreground lock time-out has expired (see SPI_GETFOREGROUNDLOCKTIMEOUT in SystemParametersInfo).
No menus are active.


I subsequently rewrote most of the code from this article(https://stackoverflow.com/a/18052274/13698760) and got something like this:
My code
uint currentThread = (uint)Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;

IntPtr activeWindow = GetForegroundWindow();

IntPtr processId = new IntPtr();
uint activeThread = GetWindowThreadProcessId(activeWindow, processId);

IntPtr windowProcess = new IntPtr();
uint windowThread = GetWindowThreadProcessId(window, windowProcess);

if (currentThread != activeThread)
    AttachThreadInput(currentThread, activeThread, true);
if (windowThread != currentThread)
    AttachThreadInput(windowThread, currentThread, true);

uint oldTimeout = 0, newTimeout = 0;
SystemParametersInfo(0x2001, 0, (IntPtr)oldTimeout, 0);
SystemParametersInfo(0x2001, 0, (IntPtr)newTimeout, 0);
LockSetForegroundWindow(2);
AllowSetForegroundWindow(uint.MaxValue);

ShowWindow(window, 9);
SetForegroundWindow(window);

SystemParametersInfo(0x2001, 0, (IntPtr)oldTimeout, 0);

if (currentThread != activeThread)
    AttachThreadInput(currentThread, activeThread, false);
if (windowThread != currentThread)
    AttachThreadInput(windowThread, currentThread, false);


int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
v($"Error bringing window to foreground: {errorCode}");

This code doesn't do what it's supposed to. In addition, I get errorCode 1300 from GetLastWin32Error(). This indicates "A privilege check failed" so I don't know if another window can still be brought to the foreground programmatically this way.
Update 1
I currently redid it a bit according to one comment and came to this, but this still doesn't work either. Process starts, but not always in foreground!
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = filePath;
p.Start();

IntPtr intPtr = p.MainWindowHandle;
SetForegroundWindow(intPtr);
ForceWindowIntoForeground(intPtr);


Why are you starting explorer if you want to open a word document? Just open the word document directly.

@RaymondChen Because I can open any files with my program. Fileopener will choose what to open them with. So it can't be done simply

I would like it to show up at the forefront of everything else: Windows already has this functionality built-in. Use Alt-Tab.

I don't know what Fileopener is. Just set UseShellExecute=true and let the system launch Word directly. Right now you are launching explorer, and then setting explorer to foreground, which doesn't help Word

@user246821 Alt-Tab is not solution for me. I need to fire it to foreground without user interaction.

@RaymondChen thakns for comment. Now I changed it to what you say, but I still have a problem and it doesn't work.

"I still have a problem and it didn't work" need more details. Note that your program must itself have foreground in order to give it away.

So, i was debuging some time and i found out this: SetForegroundWindow is returning false, even if i try another methods ShowWindowAsync, SetWindowPos etc. i get false. My application is built to run in the background, but I need to bring open processes to the foreground. Error code 1300 from GetLastWin32Error indicates that I don't have permissions to open the window in foreground.

Here is starting process
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = filePath;
p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
p.Start();
SetWindowToForeground(p);

There may be a lot of unnecessary code, but this solution works for me in all cases. (Excel, Word etc...)
private static void SetWindowToForeground(Process p)
{
    App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate
    {
        var mainWindow = Application.Current.MainWindow;
        if (mainWindow == null) throw new ShowInForegroundCapsaException("Main window is null");
        
        mainWindow.Hide();
        mainWindow.Show();
        mainWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
        mainWindow.Activate();
        mainWindow.Topmost = true;
        mainWindow.Topmost = false;
        mainWindow.Focus();
        mainWindow.Activate();
    });

    // Wait for process to fully start and get idle state
    p.WaitForInputIdle();

    // Wait until the process's main window handle is not null
    for (int i = 0; i < 10 && p.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
    
    //1) The foreground process has not disabled calls to SetForegroundWindow by a previous call to the LockSetForegroundWindow function.)
    LockSetForegroundWindow(2); // Unlock
    
    const uint SPI_SETFOREGROUNDLOCKTIMEOUT = 0x2000;
    SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETFOREGROUNDLOCKTIMEOUT, 0, 0, 0);
    
    uint foreThread = 0;
    uint threadIdentify = GetWindowThreadProcessId(p.MainWindowHandle, out foreThread);
    uint appThread = (uint)GetCurrentThreadId();
    
    v($"Foreground thread attaching log -> ThreadIdentify: {threadIdentify}, Fore thread: {foreThread}, App thread: {appThread}", false);
    
    if (foreThread != appThread) {
        AttachThreadInput(foreThread, appThread, true);
        BringWindowToTop(p.MainWindowHandle);
        ShowWindow(p.MainWindowHandle, 5);
        AttachThreadInput(foreThread, appThread, false);
    }
    else
    {
        BringWindowToTop(p.MainWindowHandle);
        ShowWindow(p.MainWindowHandle, 5);
    }

    // Set active window to foreground
    SetForegroundWindow(p.MainWindowHandle);
}

I hope this solution will help you. If you want to know in detail why I used everything the way I did, then read these pages that deal with the subject.
Microsoft SetForegroundWindow documentation
Stackoverflow AttachThreadInput
SetForegroundWindow changing in time
